# In vim I want to find a string and insert spaces in between each character of the string

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

I have been trying to search and replace with regex and capture groups in a simple way, but have no idea how.

Let's say I want to operate on the previous sentence capturing "trying" and replacing with "t r y i n g".

```
:%s/\vtrying{-}/ \1/g
```

Comment: `%s/(.)/ \1/g` then `%s/^ *\| *$//g`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are suggesting, do I replace my string with * in the second search?

Comment: no in the second part, just replace all the spaces which exists at the start or at the end with an empty string. I don't whether vim uses `|` or `\|` for orring.

Comment: May be helpful https://regex101.com/r/wH1nK1/1

Comment: @Sachink thinkl vim won't support lookarounds.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm trying to only insert spaces in between characters in a specific string that occurs several times in a file. Where do I specify the particular string I am interested in in your example?

Comment: @Sachink cool website thanks for the link vim seems to have a different syntax for look ahead @<= but I still can formulate an expression with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a solution, but here is a different one:

```
 %s/trying/\=join(split(submatch(0),'\zs'), ' ')/g
```

That should be a little bit faster than the substitute() call, not that this matters much.

Comment: Great solution and this captures non letter characters which I didn't mention in the question but is also important in my implementation!

Answer (score 4):

Just do two substitute matches. Where the second one uses the substitute with an expression (`\=` at the beginning of the replacement `:h sub-replace-expression`)

```
:%s/trying/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\w\zs\ze\w', ' ', 'g')/
```

The expression just inserts a space between every word character.

Comment: That worked very well thanks so much! I had never encountered sub-replace-expression before, that's real handy:)

Comment: If you end it with another g, like  `...' ', 'g')/g` , it will work for multiple matches within a line as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been trying to search and replace with regex and capture groups
>   in a simple way, but have no idea how.
>
> Let's say I want to operate on the previous sentence capturing
>   "trying" and replacing with "t r y i n g".

```
:g~trying~exe "norm /trying^Mve^[" | s/\%V\(.\)/\1 /g
```

(Where the `^M` is entered by CTRL-Q Enter, and `^[` is CTRL-Q Esc)

> I have been t r y i n g  to search and replace with regex and capture
>   groups in a simple way, but have no idea how.
>
> Let's say I want to operate on the previous sentence capturing "t r y
>   i n g " and replacing with "t r y i n g".

NB this will, I think, only work for one instance of 'trying' on a line.

The `g` global command matches lines with 'trying' in them, then runs 'execute' with the 'normal' command to jump to it, visually select it, then the | separates another command, which does a search and replace of any character within the `\%V` visual selection, with the character and a space.

It also adds a space at the end.

All in all, it's not as good as @FDinoff's answer.