# Add spaces between characters on a visual selection in Vim

Tags: vim

To add visual interest to my comments and/or text notes, I usually put 1 space between each part of characters, like this:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
// VERY IMPORTANT NOTE
//////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////
// V E R Y   I M P O R T A N T   N O T E
//////////////////////////////////////////
```

This is simple enough with a "normal" editor (you just press `<right arrow> <space>` until the end of the word/line), but now that I'm getting used to Vim, it feels so weird: there has to be a better way.

Also in Vim isn't that easy: I can obviously create a macro with "`a <space> <esc> l`", but it's a little clumsy, especially because you have to count how many times you want to repeat the macro.
Is there a way to visually select a line/word/whatever and do what I need to do automatically?

I read [this answer here on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599577/in-vim-i-want-to-find-a-string-and-insert-spaces-in-between-each-character-of-th) which basically achieve what I want with a regex `[%s/pattern/\=join(split(submatch(0),'\zs'), ' ')/g]`, but I can't come up with a way of using my visual selection instead of a specific pattern.

Any idea before I start thinking how to create a plugin?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about :

```
:xnoremap µ s<c-r>=substitute(@", '.\ze.', '& ', 'g')<cr>
```

`v_s` cut the selection and put it in the default register `@"`, then you can re-inject it transformed thanks to `i_CTRL-R=` and `substitute()`. You can also use `split()` + `join()` instead if you prefer, but `\ze.` already takes care of not adding an extra space after the last character selected.

Comment: That's actually pretty close, thanks!! Only a couple of "imperfections": it adds a space before the selection and it doesn't work that good with a selected line [using the V command] (I guess the problem is the newline character, which it isn't skipped by the substitution, so you get `<space><newline><space>`). But hey, you are already 98% there.... can you get to 100%? :D

Comment: Also, I added a final <esc> to the mapping, to better "wrap it up".

Comment: I introduced a regression with my edit, it should be `.\ze.`

Comment: For the other problem I found a stupid but effective solution: I mapped the command in normal mode adding a "select all the line but the newline char" command `(0v$h)`, and changed your command slightly to exist only in the visual mode:

`vnoremap µ s<c-r>=substitute(@", '.\ze.', '& ', 'g')<cr><esc>`
`nnoremap µ 0v$hs<c-r>=substitute(@", '.\ze.', '& ', 'g')<cr><esc>`

99.9% perfect. :)

Let me know if you want to update your answer or you are happy with it as it is. And thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, here is the full solution I adopted.

Based on Luc Hermitte answer, I ended up mapping  in 2 different modes.

The first one in visual mode:

`vnoremap ç s<c-r>=substitute(@", '.\ze.', '& ', 'g')<cr><esc>`

This simply apply Luc's brilliant solution, adding spaces between all selected characters.

The second one in normal mode:

`nnoremap ç 0v$hs<c-r>=substitute(@", '.\ze.', '& ', 'g')<cr><esc>`

This one, very similarly, pre-select (with `0v$h`) in visual mode the current line except the final newline character, before applying Luc's command.

Very useful stuff, and I learned lots of things in the process!

Hope it's useful, enjoy Vim :)